# Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods error with "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE"

Tags: express, cors

First, here is my middleware code that most other answers say fixes the concern:

```
//enable CORS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

I know for sure the GET and POST methods work, but anytime I try to delete something on my site, I get an error. Here is my delete method:

```
deleteSaved(title, data, url) {
    return axios.delete("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/daniels-first-database/collections/nytcollection?apiKey=*APIKEYHERE*", {
        params: {
        "title": title,
        "data": data,
        "url": url
        }
    })
    .then(function(results) {
        console.log("axios results", results);
        return results;
    });
}
```

Everything works on a local development server, so I don't think it has anything to do with my method, but there it is just in case.

Comment: Check this out: [https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/509](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/509)

Comment: I checked it out. What am I looking at? I'm still kind of new to this so forgive me for being ignorant.

Comment: Where does `deleteSaved` live, I'm assuming that's in the browser? You seem to be calling out directly to mlab using CORS, so your Express code won't even be hit by that request. Take a look at the request in the Network section of your browser's dev tools, see what headers are coming back. I suggest proxying all DB requests via your Express server rather than having the browser connect directly.

Comment: @Daniel It looks axios /might/ be misbehaving if you don't handle the body for your request properly.  According to the documentation for Axios, the config parameters passed into the `.delete` method don't need a `url` or `data` parameter. I'd make sure your request is setup exactly how axios wants. And @skrirtle has good advice. I'd only add that you can use something like [https://requestb.in](https://requestb.in) to get a temporary url you can send requests to, which can be another easy way of figuring out what you're sending with your `.delete`

Answer (score 1):

On the response header of your server API, add:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```